# php login system invalid credentials is not appearing

Tags: php, mysql

this is the php code for fetching sql with if condition

```
 if ($result) {
        if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['email'];
            setcookie('username_cookie', $row['username'], time() + (24 * 60 * 60), '/water');
            // Login successful, redirect to the dashboard or another page
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            // Login failed, set the error message
            $errorMessage = "Invalid username or password";
            header("Location: login.php?error=" . urlencode($errorMessage));
            exit();
        }
    }
```

html code that belongs to the form with 2 inputs:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <h2 class="fw-bolder">Login</h2>
            <div class="card-body">
            <?php if (isset($errorMessage)): ?>
                    <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <form action="login1.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <a href="signup.php" class="btn btn-primary">Signup</a>
                    <?php if (isset($errorMessage)): ?>
                    <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want that error message appears it's currently not appearing with this configuration

Comment: Where on the form are you setting `$errorMessage`? You have it set in the first code block, but considering it redirects on the error, it won't exist in the second block unless you're setting it above.

Comment: <?php if (isset($errorMessage)): ?>
                    <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
you can see it below submit button

Comment: Yes, that's where you're checking to see if it's set. But where do you attempt to set it? When you go back to `login.php`, it has a query parameter of `$_GET['error']`. Do you attempt to retrieve it at all?

Comment: You're probably intending to do `if (isset($_GET['error']))` and `echo $_GET['error'];` instead of using `$errorMessage` in login.php.